# R: reset values in data frame based on a value range

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, reset

I have a data frame like so:

```
# generate data frame
df = as.data.frame(cbind(c('Chr1', 'Chr1', 'Chr1', 'Chr2', 'Chr2', 'Chr2', 'Chr3', 'Chr3', 'Chr4', 'Chr4', 'Chr5'), 
                         c(121, 1567, 2489, 23, 565, 1789, 551, 1987, 25, 2356, 1111)))
colnames(df) = c('Chr', 'Pos')
df$Pos = as.numeric(df$Pos)
df
```

> ```
>     Chr  Pos
> 1  Chr1  121
> 2  Chr1 1567
> 3  Chr1 2489
> 4  Chr2   23
> 5  Chr2  565
> 6  Chr2 1789
> 7  Chr3  551
> 8  Chr3 1987
> 9  Chr4   25
> 10 Chr4 2356
> 11 Chr5 1111
> ```

Now, I want to change the values in the column `Pos` depending on its current value. For example, if the value in `Pos` <= 1000, it should get `500` assigned in the new column, if the value is <= 2000 but > 1000 it should get `1000` assigned in the new column, etc.

The easy approach with `df` would look like this:

```
# alter dataframe
df$Pos = ifelse(df$Pos <= 1000, 500, df$Pos)
df$Pos = ifelse(df$Pos <= 2000 & df$Pos > 1000, 1500, df$Pos)
df$Pos = ifelse(df$Pos <= 3000 & df$Pos > 2000, 2500, df$Pos)
df
```

> ```
>     Chr  Pos
> 1  Chr1  500
> 2  Chr1 1500
> 3  Chr1 2500
> 4  Chr2  500
> 5  Chr2  500
> 6  Chr2 1500
> 7  Chr3  500
> 8  Chr3 1500
> 9  Chr4  500
> 10 Chr4 2500
> 11 Chr5 1500
> ```

This results in the desired output. However, my real dataset is much larger and I cannot add an extra condition for each range of values that I want to reset. I am therefore looking for a more efficient solution. This is my attempt at a more efficient solution:

```
# generate reference vectors
bin = seq(from = 1000, by = 1000, length.out = 3)
pos = seq(from = 500, by = 1000, length.out = 3)

# reset values
df$Pos = ifelse(df$Pos <= bin & df$Pos > bin-1000, pos, df$Pos)
df
```

However, this throws a warning message:

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In df$Pos <= bin :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> 2: In df$Pos > bin - 1000 :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ```

And the output looks wrong (some values have been reset, others have not been):

> ```
> > df
>     Chr  Pos
> 1  Chr1  500
> 2  Chr1 1500
> 3  Chr1 2500
> 4  Chr2  500
> 5  Chr2  565
> 6  Chr2 1789
> 7  Chr3  500
> 8  Chr3 1500
> 9  Chr4   25
> 10 Chr4 2356
> 11 Chr5 1500
> ```

I also tried solving my issue with a `Map` function as well, but that did not work either. See below for my attempt with `Map`:

```
df2 = Map(function(bin, bin2, pos) {
  df2 = ifelse(df$Pos <= 1000 & df$Pos > bin2, pos, df$Pos)
}, bin, bin-1000, pos)
df2
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>  [1]  500 1567 2489  500  500 1789  500 1987  500 2356 1111
>
> [[2]]
>  [1]  121 1567 2489   23  565 1789  551 1987   25 2356 1111
>
> [[3]]
>  [1]  121 1567 2489   23  565 1789  551 1987   25 2356 1111
> ```

I feel like I am approaching this problem from a totally wrong angle. Anyone has any idea how to solve this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take help of `cut` or `findInterval`.

```
bin = c(0, seq(from = 1000, by = 1000, length.out = 3))
pos = seq(from = 500, by = 1000, length.out = 3)

df$new_value <- cut(df$Pos, bin, pos)
#cut returns factor output, to change to numbers use the below code
df$new_value <- as.numeric(as.character(df$new_value))
df

#    Chr  Pos new_value
#1  Chr1  121       500
#2  Chr1 1567      1500
#3  Chr1 2489      2500
#4  Chr2   23       500
#5  Chr2  565       500
#6  Chr2 1789      1500
#7  Chr3  551       500
#8  Chr3 1987      1500
#9  Chr4   25       500
#10 Chr4 2356      2500
#11 Chr5 1111      1500
```

For clarity and explanation of the answer, I have created a new column `new_value` you can replace the original column `Pos` if that is what you want to do.